# Routing is not working in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I am trying to do routing in angular 2 but it is not working.I have a listing page where I listed some News.When the user clicks the news it have to redirects to the details page.But it is not working and I am not getting any error in console.

**Listing.component.html:**

```
    <div *ngFor="let List of HomeList |slice :1:5;let isFirstRow=first;let last=last;" >
       <button (click)="getDetail(List.ArticleId)">Get Detail</button>
        <a [routerLink]="['/detail', List.ArticleId]">
          <h4 [ngClass]="(isFirstRow)?'TopLeftNews':'TopLesftOtherNews'">
            {{List.HeadLine}}
           </h4>
        </a>
         <time>{{List.UpdatedDate}}</time>
         <p class="TopLeftAbstract">{{List.Abstract}}</p>
         <hr *ngIf="!last" class="hr-1x">
    </div>
```

**Listing.component.cs:**

```
getDetail(id:any): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/detail', id]);
}
```

**app.routing.ts:**

```
const MainMenu_Routes:Routes=[
    {
        //Redirect to a URL
        path:'',
        redirectTo:'/home',
        pathMatch:'full'
    },
    {
        //Mapping a Route to a Component 
        path:'home',
        component:HomeComponent
    },
    { 
        //Handling "Page Not Found"
        path: "**",
        redirectTo:"/home"
    },
    { 
        //Configure Parameters 
        path: 'detail/:id', 
        component: ArticleDetailComponent 
    }, 

];

export const Const_Routing=RouterModule.forRoot(MainMenu_Routes);
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ArticleDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    Const_Routing,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [SharedService,IndexedDBService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: the `page not found` route needs to be at the bottom of the route array

Comment: Its working....Thnk you

Answer (score -1):

Routes that are generic, that catch incorrect routes, need to be at the end of the routes array. While the router looks through the array, if it gets to a generic route, it will use it and not pass so it has to be the last route in the array.

Try changing your routes to:

```
[
    {
        //Redirect to a URL
        path:'',
        redirectTo:'/home',
        pathMatch:'full'
    },
    {
        //Mapping a Route to a Component 
        path:'home',
        component:HomeComponent
    },
    { 
        //Configure Parameters 
        path: 'detail/:id', 
        component: ArticleDetailComponent 
    },
    { 
        //Handling "Page Not Found"
        path: "**",
        redirectTo:"/home"
    }
];
```